# Microcharts in Listview Using Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, charts, prism

I'm using xamarin.forms and I need to create graphs inside of listview, how to create graphs inside of listview using microcharts.

This is my code in xaml:

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                            <!--<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Tapped="TargetList_Tapped"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>-->
                            <Grid
                                  HeightRequest="10"/>
                            <customRenderer:CustomFrame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="30" Padding="15">

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                                    <!--<Image x:Name="sam"/>-->


                                    <Label Text="{Binding AreaNo}"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       Font="Bold"/>

                                    <StackLayout Margin="0, -5, 0, 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1" HeightRequest="150"/>
                                        <Label Text="Last Covered On:" 
                                           TextColor="Black"
                                           Font="10"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           Opacity="0.6"/>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding DateCovered}" 
                                           TextColor="Black"
                                           Font="10"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           Opacity="0.6"/>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                </StackLayout>

                            </customRenderer:CustomFrame>
                            <customRenderer:CustomFrame Padding="0" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0">
                                <Image x:Name="sampleImage" Source="Rectangle_Inactive.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                            </customRenderer:CustomFrame>


                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This is my code in xaml.cs:

```
namespace PrismUnityApp6.Views
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>
    {
        new Entry(200)
        {
            Color = SKColor.Parse("#008000"),
        },
        new Entry(400)
        {
            Color = SKColor.Parse("#FFFFFF")
        }

    };

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        Chart1.Chart = new RadialGaugeChart { Entries = entries };

    }
}
```

}

I tried this code but I can't get the name of the chart in xaml.cs file while using listview.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chart inside ItemTemplate. Possibly there could many charts and they can't have same name. Correct approach is to use binding inside ItemTemplate.

Similar issue is discussed [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82032/cannot-reach-control-x-name-inside-listview).

This example is just for demonstration how it could possibly work. After you try this demo make sure you learn MVVM pattern and use it in your project.

**The MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView
       x:Name="MyListview">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <microcharts:ChartView Chart="{Binding ChartData}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<MyChart> MyCharts;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCharts = new List<MyChart>();
        PopulateCharts();
    }

    private void PopulateCharts()
    {
        MyCharts.Add(new MyChart() { ChartData = Chart1 });
        MyCharts.Add(new MyChart() { ChartData = Chart2 });
        MyListview.ItemsSource = MyCharts;
    }

    public class MyChart
    {
        public Chart ChartData { get; set; }
    }

    public Chart Chart1 => new BarChart()
    {
        Entries = new[]
        {
             new Microcharts.Entry(128)
             {
                 Label = "iOS",
                 ValueLabel = "128",
                 Color = SKColor.Parse("#b455b6")
             },
             new Microcharts.Entry(514)
             {
                 Label = "Shared",
                 ValueLabel = "514",
                 Color = SKColor.Parse("#3498db")
        }},
        BackgroundColor = SKColors.White
    };


    public Chart Chart2 => new BarChart()
    {
        Entries = new[]
        {
             new Microcharts.Entry(128)
             {
                 Label = "Android",
                 ValueLabel = "128",
                 Color = SKColor.Parse("#b455b6")
             },
             new Microcharts.Entry(514)
             {
                 Label = "UWP",
                 ValueLabel = "514",
                 Color = SKColor.Parse("#3498db")
        }},
        BackgroundColor = SKColors.Yellow
    };
}
```

Also in the blog post that I mentioned there is a nice example using MVVM pattern [here on this link](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts.Samples/tree/master/Bikr/Bikr).

Comment: Do you have resources on how to create charts using binding? Sorry, I'm new to xamarin.

Comment: What exactly do you want to implement? Do you need to have one or more chart on one single page?

Comment: I would use these charts.. https://blog.xamarin.com/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/

Comment: Yes, I need one or more charts on one single page

Comment: but how do I use it for binding?

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is working. You saved my day