# Show Microcharts.Chart in custom ViewCell

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, commandparameter

I have a ListView with custom ViewCell.
ViewCell contains Microcharts.Chart. I use binding and try to find a way to show particular chart in ListView item depending on some condition (because charts are absent for now).

Here is a part of XAML code:

```
        <ListView x:Name="blocksList"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MainPageBlocks}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>

                        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                      
                    ... some elements

                        <forms:ChartView
                            x:name="LineChart"   
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Chart="{Binding MyChart}">

                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Chart entries:

```
        private readonly List<Microcharts.Entry> _entries = new List<Microcharts.Entry>()
        {
            new Microcharts.Entry(200)
            {
                Color=SKColor.Parse("#FF0033")
            },

            new Microcharts.Entry(400)
            {
                Color=SKColor.Parse("#FF8000")
            },

            new Microcharts.Entry(300)
            {
                Color=SKColor.Parse("#FFE600")
            },

            new Microcharts.Entry(250)
            {
                Color=SKColor.Parse("#1AB34D")
            },

            new Microcharts.Entry(650)
            {
                Color=SKColor.Parse("#1A66FF")
            },

            new Microcharts.Entry(500)
            {
                Color=SKColor.Parse("#801AB3")
            }
        };
```

As for the code behind, I tried different ways:

```
LineChart.BindingContext = new Microcharts.LineChart { Entries = _entries };
```

Then I tried to bind List of ChartViews:

```
public List<Microcharts.Chart> ChartCollection { get; set; }

    public Microcharts.Chart LineChart1
    {
        get
        {
            return new LineChart()
            {
                Entries = _entries,
                LineMode = LineMode.Straight,
                PointMode = PointMode.Circle,
                PointSize = 20,
                BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent,
            };
        }
    }

    public Microcharts.Chart LineChart2
    {
        get
        {
            return new LineChart()
            {
                Entries = _entries,
                LineMode = LineMode.Straight,
                PointMode = PointMode.Circle,
                PointSize = 20,
                BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent,
            };
        }
    }

ChartCollection = new List<Chart>();
ChartCollection.Add(LineChart1);
ChartCollection.Add(LineChart2);
```

There are no errors during compilation, chartView are absent, the rest of the views are visible.
What should i do to show ChartView inside ViewCell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody knows an answer?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is how to show ChartView in the ViewCell?

Comment: Very hard to understand what is your issue. Showing a ChartView in a ViewCell should work => <ViewCell><forms:ChartView  .. /></ViewCell> As for condition you can use DataTemplateSelector for example.

Comment: ChartView shows outside of ListView (ViewCell), but inside ViewCell doesn't. Do you have code example how to show ChartView inside ViewCell?

Comment: Why DataTemplateSelector? All of my ListView items are the same.

Comment: Then please update your question, put more details and the related code. A screenshot may add extra value.

Comment: “All of my ListView items are the same.” -> LineChart is not the same as PointChart.

Comment: I've edited my question. I tried to show only LineChart views, not BarChart or other types of Charts.

Comment: I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346227/microcharts-in-listview-using-xamarin, but it doesn't help

Comment: Using DataTemplateSelector ChartView still not displayed. The same code outside of ViewCell shows ChartView. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Did you try to set ListView.HasUnevenRows Property to true or explicitly enlarge the row height?

Comment: Thanks, EvZ, I found a desicion! The reason was that I new in Xamarin.Forms. If someone needs a code, I'll post.

Comment: Did I help you or you managed to find the answer yourself?

Comment: Partly. Thank you for participating EvZ